# Launch app using package name

Tags: android, null, launcher

I am trying to launch an application from my own application in Android. What i have done is get all the package names of the apps installed into the device and stored them into a String Array. Then with a list view i try to launch every app selected.

In order to create a new intent to launch every app i use the following code claimed to work in several posts in android tutorial sites:

```
Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packages[arg2]);
```

where packages is the name of my table containing the package names and arg2 the listview selected item.

The problem is that even if i check with toast messages i can see the package name is correct but the getLaunchIntentForPackage is always null and the apps are not starting.

Thanks

Comment: Show some more code. What is the packages array and what is arg2?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but it seems that the OS would prevent apps from launching other apps... unless they are from the same organization and live within the same sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
String pack[] = {"com.android.setting", "com.android.browser"};     
try {
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(pack[0]);
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // returns null if application is not installed
}
```

Comment: That will only start the broswer, and what is with the pack thing?

Comment: thats an example because i dont know your packages.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the intent

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```